# Get the name of caller method

Tags: c#

Suppose, I am calling GetMethodB() which is passed as an argument to GetmethodA() and GetMethodAA(). How do I get the name of these method who invokes GetMethodB();

```
ClassName.GetMethodA(GetMethodB());
ClassName.GetMethodAA(GetMethodB());
```

Comment: Why do you need to?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually I need a name of GetMethodA() and GetMethodAA() from inside GetMethodB(). Hope this clears my problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't clear your problem at all.  I suspect you're trying to over-engineer a complex solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.  But since we don't know what you're actually trying to do, I doubt anybody here can be of much help.  With the information given, all I can suggest is that you add a `string` parameter to the method signature and pass in the name of the method via that parameter.  Something like: `GetMEthodA(GetMethodB("GetMethodA"))`

Comment: @David, I am reading files with same extension. And there are only two files in a directory. First file has information on something else and second has information about something else. 
So, depending upon from where GetMethodB() gets call, I will return the Path of which is being read. And based on this, i have different implementation.

Comment: That sounds like an *amazingly* broken design.

Comment: [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) may help to achieve what looked like you need based on post, also not exactly going to work in case shown. Completely not related to your goal stated in comment so...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it: at the time `GetMethodB` is invoked, neither `GetMethodA` nor `GetMethodAA` is active.

The invocation sequence looks like this:

- Your method calls `GetMethodB()`, and gets its result
- Your method calls `GetMethodA(...)` passing it the result of `GetMethodB()` call
- Your method calls `GetMethodB()` again, and gets its result
- Your method calls `GetMethodAA(...)` passing it the result of the second `GetMethodB()` call

In both cases the caller of `GetMethodB` is your current method, from which the invocation is done.

If `GetMethodB` needs to know its caller, then you should identify the caller to the method explicitly - for example, by passing an `enum` or a `string` parameter.

Comment: Have tried passing a additional string parameter onto 
GetMethodB(index, system.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)

Comment: @SantoshThapa You missed the point of the answer: you cannot do it automatically, because the context is not available at the time of the call. You need something that looks like `ClassName.GetMethodA(GetMethodB("GetMethodA"))` - i.e. tells `GetMethodB` that its result is going to be used in `GetMethodA`.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods are called with the result of getmethodB, so the caller of getmethodB is the same one as the caller of getmethodA and/or getmethodAA. 
You cannot find out to which method the result of another method is passed.

- So first getMethodB is called,
- the result is captured
- and passed to the other methods.

Callstacks or any other tricks won't help here.

Answer (score -1):

Use the StackFrame

```
var sf = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1);
var callingMethodName = sf.GetMethod().Name;
```

Comment: This would give him the method that the code he showed is defined in, but that's not what he says he wants.

Comment: Plus, this can give wildly different results depending if the code is debug vs. release. Callers may be optimized out.

Comment: If he invokes GetMethodB from within GetMethodA, which is what it appears he is intending to do, it should yield GetMethodA. It gets the calling method name from the execution stack.

Comment: I thought so first too Kevin but he is not passing a delegate to `GetMethodA` to be executed from within. He is first executing `GetMethodB` and passing the return value as parameter to `GetMethodA` instead.

Comment: Yes, stack trace is not helping me for this problem.